# How to make a seekBar with negative values?

Tags: java, android, material-components-android, android-slider

I tried some libraries from Github but either they don't work or I couldn't figure out how to make them work.

I just want to create a seekbar with float values, with a center of 0.

Comment: you can make some transformation to positive values before setting them onto the seakbar

Comment: I would go with a class extends View and draw it myself, get some code from the current seek bars available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Slider` in the Material Components Library

```
    <com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:labelBehavior="withinBounds"
        android:valueFrom="-10.0"
        android:valueTo="10.0"
        android:stepSize="1.0"/>
```

[image]

**NOTE:** it requires the version **`1.2.0`** (currently 1.2.0-rc01) of the library.

Comment: @User104163 You can find all the info [here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android). The minSdk = 14.